# Mahāsamādhi in Buddhism?

Tags: karma, samadhi

Wikipedia defines [Mahāsamādhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahasam%C4%81dhi) as follows:

> Mahāsamādhi (the great and final samādhi) is the act of consciously
>   and intentionally leaving one's body. A realized yogi (male) or
>   yogini (female) who has attained the state of nirvikalpa samādhi,
>   will, at an appropriate time, consciously exit from their body. [...] This is not the same as the physical death that occurs for an unenlightened person. <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahasam%C4%81dhi)</sup>

A non-practitioner of Yoga would call this 'dying at will'.

Is there a similar concept in Buddhism?

Comment: Voted to close. Question likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts because this has to do with comparing Buddhism to other religions and we don't study those here. If you study Buddhism you can compare it yourself to whatever intetests you. Buddhism is like nothing else and it's not explained in terms of an another religion.

Answer (score 0):

miccha-samadhi (wrong/defiled concentration). And to think the mind is in the body is also miccha-samadhi if so perceived.

Comment: Dhammapada 37. Dwelling in the cave, the mind, without form, wanders far and alone. Dūraṅgamaṃ ekacaraṃ , asarīraṃ guhāsayaṃ. New Concise Pali English Dictionary
guhāsaya
mfn.
being in the body. https://suttacentral.net/define/guh%C4%81saya

Answer (score 0):

> the act of consciously and intentionally leaving one's body.

I haven't ran across any Buddhist suttas that mention the above as a practice of the Buddhism's samadhi. In Buddhism, they don't concern much with "maha" samadhi. Instead they focus more on Samma-Samadhi/Right-Concentration, which is a link in the [Noble Eightfold Path](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/bodhi/waytoend.html). Refer to this [dictionary's definition](http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/s_t/samaadhi.htm) for further details from Buddhism's perspective.

Comment: I've clarified the answer and added that it means death (more or less).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is mahasamadi in buddhism but there is mind made body. This is what the Buddha said about mind made body in DN 2.

> With his mind thus concentrated, purified, and bright, unblemished, free from defects, pliant, malleable, steady, and attained to imperturbability, he directs and inclines it to creating a mind-made body. From this body he creates another body, endowed with form, made of the mind, complete in all its parts, not inferior in its faculties. Just as if a man were to draw a reed from its sheath. The thought would occur to him: 'This is the sheath, this is the reed. The sheath is one thing, the reed another, but the reed has been drawn out from the sheath.' Or as if a man were to draw a sword from its scabbard. The thought would occur to him: 'This is the sword, this is the scabbard. The sword is one thing, the scabbard another, but the sword has been drawn out from the scabbard.' Or as if a man were to pull a snake out from its slough. The thought would occur to him: 'This is the snake, this is the slough. The snake is one thing, the slough another, but the snake has been pulled out from the slough.' In the same way — with his mind thus concentrated, purified, and bright, unblemished, free from defects, pliant, malleable, steady, and attained to imperturbability, the monk directs and inclines it to creating a mind-made body. From this body he creates another body, endowed with form, made of the mind, complete in all its parts, not inferior in its faculties.
>
> "This, too, great king, is a fruit of the contemplative life, visible here and now, more excellent than the previous ones and more sublime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The concept of relinquishing the will to live can be found in Buddhism.

From [DN 16](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html):

> And the Blessed One said: "Whosoever, Ananda, has developed,
>   practiced, employed, strengthened, maintained, scrutinized, and
>   brought to perfection the four constituents of psychic power could, if
>   he so desired, remain throughout a world-period or until the end of
>   it. The Tathagata, Ananda, has done so. Therefore the Tathagata could,
>   if he so desired, remain throughout a world-period or until the end of
>   it."
>
> (And later)
>
> When this was said, the Blessed One spoke to Mara, the Evil One,
>   saying: "Do not trouble yourself, Evil One. Before long the
>   Parinibbana of the Tathagata will come about. Three months hence the
>   Tathagata will utterly pass away."
>
> And at the Capala shrine the Blessed One thus mindfully and clearly
>   comprehending renounced his will to live on. And upon the Lord's
>   renouncing his will to live on, there came a tremendous earthquake,
>   dreadful and astonishing, and thunder rolled across the heavens.
>
> **Commentary (Sister Vajira & Francis Story):**
>
> *Kappam va tittheyya kappavasesam* va. Comy. takes *kappa* not as
>   "world-period" or "aeon," but as *ayu-kappa*, "life span," and explains
>   *avasesa* (usually "remainder") by "in excess." Comy.: "He may stay
>   alive completing the life span pertaining to men at the given time.
>   (Sub. Comy.: the maximum life span.) *Kappavasesa*: 'in excess'
>   (*atireka*), i.e., more or less above the hundred years said to be the
>   normally highest life expectation."
>
> Among the numerous meanings of the word kappa, there is, in fact, that
>   of time in general (*kala*) and not only the duration of an aeon; but
>   the meaning "life span" seems to have been ascribed to it only in this
>   passage. Also, the meaning "in excess" for *avasesa* (usually
>   "remainder") is unusual.
>
> The four constituents of psychic power (*iddhipada*) are concentration
>   due to zeal, energy, purity of mind, and investigation.

The [Anandajoti translation](https://suttacentral.net/dn16/en/anandajoti) states:

> Whoever has developed, Ānanda, made much of, carried on, established,
>   maintained, augmented, and properly instigated the Four Paths to
>   Power, could, if he wanted, Ānanda, remain for the lifespan or for
>   what is left of the lifespan. The Realised One has developed, Ānanda,
>   made much of, carried on, established, maintained, augmented, and
>   properly instigated the Four Paths to Power. If he wanted, Ānanda, the
>   Realised One could remain for the lifespan or for what is left of the
>   lifespan.”